# Emulator images (avds) not found when trying to run Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, qr-code

I'm currently trying to create an app that reads QR Code with Cordova. I'm only creating the app to run in android.enter code here
I've installed SDK packages with android.bat file. 
- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- ARM 64 v8a System Image
- Android 7.0 (API 24)
- Andrlid 6.0 (API 23)
- Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

I was able to build successfully but getting the following error message.

Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat" sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat" avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver